# What unit test method can I write for the Delete action using xunit and moq?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, moq, xunit, in-memory-database

```
public class Product
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{

        private readonly DataBaseContext _context;
        public ProductService(DataBaseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        public Product GetById(long id)
        {
            return _context.Products.Find(id);
        }

        public void Remove(long id)
        {
            var product = _context.Products.Find(id);
            _context.Products.Remove(product);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I created the following code using **scaffolding** and I want to write a test using **xunit** and **moq**:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
        private readonly IProductService _productService;

        public ProductController(IProductService productService)
        {
            _productService = productService;
        }


     // GET: ProductController/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
    
            return View(_productService.GetById(id));
    
        }
    
        // POST: ProductController/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                _productService.Remove(id);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
 }
```

I installed the following packages on the main project And I made the relevant settings in startup:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory

I installed the following packages on the test project:

- Moq

**What unit test method can I write for the Delete action?**

Answer (score 0):

I would write 2 tests specifically for the delete function of your service. For the controller, I would probably do test using WebApplicationFactory to do the whole flow (caveat, I’m not 100% sure this is possible with mvc controllers).

For the service test, I would want to know: what happens when I pass in an id that exists? What happens when I pass in an id that doesn’t exist (Should it throw an exception etc)?

Both simply done by building your in memory database in your test and calling your service code. You can then validate that the database has removed the record with id “x”.

Example:

```
[Fact]
Public void WhenDeletingItsmThatExistsInDatabase_ShouldRemoveFromDatabase()
{
    var ctx = new DbContext();
    ctx.Products.Add(product with id 1);
    ctx.SaveChanges():
    var sut = new ProductService(ctx);
    sut.Delete(1);
    Assert.Empty(ctx.Products);
}
```